# Setting up remote debugging over an ssh tunnel .net VisualStudio

Tags: .net, remote-debugging, ssh-tunnel

The I have an ssh session open to a remote box running a .net process. I have installed the remote debugger.

I have set up tunnel for tcp/135, tcp/139, tcp/445, udp/137, and udp/138.

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you finally find success in doing this?

Comment: Nope. Ended up just doing a ton of logging.

Comment: Same here... MS need to learn a lot of things from the open source community...

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://apocryph.org/2006/09/13/visual_studio_remote_debug_monitor_if_i_didnt_love_it_so_much_id_hate_it/) article suggests that because remote debugging uses DCOM, there is two-way communication  and that the remote client needs to talk to tcp/135 on **your** machine. You will need to give the remote machine access via another tunnel in the other direction.

Comment: No dice. There is something else in the firewall.